# OpenCL kernel for working with 3 Bytes blocks

Tags: opencl

I have a OpenCL kernel, which changes the bit order within 24 bit wide blocks.

My first attempt to realize this is to create `buffersize/3` threads, but somehow my OpenCl kernel works slower as the same algorithm on the CPU (2 GHz Intel Core i7).

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

__kernel void decode(
  __global uint8_t* in,
  __global uint8_t* out,
  const unsigned int count) {
    int i = get_global_id(0)*3;

    if(i<count){
        out[i]=in[i];
        out[i+1]=(in[i+1]&0b00001111)<<4|(in[i+2]&0b11110000)>>4;
        out[i+2]=(in[i+2]&0b00001111)<<4|(in[i+1]&0b11110000)>>4;
    }
}
```

This kernel is called this way:

```
count = buffersize/3; // buffersize is approx. 6 to 8 MB
error = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(
        commands, 
        koDecode, 
        1, 
        NULL, 
        &count, 
        NULL, 
        0, 
        NULL, 
        NULL);
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve in your algorithm, but you should use CL vectors. Something within the line of the following:

```
__kernel void decode(
            __global uchar3* in,
            __global uchar3* out,
            const unsigned int count)
{
   int i = get_global_id(0);
   out[i] = out[i].zyx;
}
```

Comment: Could use uchar16 to fit 5 times the density into single operation and SIMD of Intel.

Comment: Thats not exactly like the OP code. You are operating on 32bits elements, while he is working on true 24bits elements. `sizeof(uchar3) = 4`

Answer (score 1):

This may be faster, since `out` "may" point to `in` most compilers don't cache global variables:

```
__kernel void decode(
  __global uint8_t* in,
  __global uint8_t* out,
  const unsigned int count) {
    int i = get_global_id(0)*3;

    if(i<count){
        out[i]=in[i];
        uint8_t t[2];
        t[0] = in[i+1];
        t[1] = in[i+2];
        out[i+1]=(t[0]&0b00001111)<<4|(t[1]&0b11110000)>>4;
        out[i+2]=(t[1]&0b00001111)<<4|(t[0]&0b11110000)>>4;
    }
}
```

Also, you don't really need the `i<count` check, if you always launch the needed amount of work items.